# How to get a model object using another model object in a template in django

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to get a model object using another model object in my template but i am unable to do so. Please help me to do so.

this is my models.py

```
class roomuser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey(rooms, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.TextField(max_length=200, default='Hey, I\'m using twitter')
    img = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')
    private = models.BooleanField(default='False')
```

this is my views.py

```
def room(request, name):
    myroom = rooms.objects.get(name=name)
    roomusers = roomuser.objects.filter(room=myroom)
    myuser = profile.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'room.html', {'room':myroom, 'users':roomusers, 'myuser':myuser})
```

this is my template view

```
{% for user in users %}
        {{user.user}}<br>
        {{user.user.username.myuser.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

i want to access a profile object by using a object of roomuser model as they both have a user class in common. Please help me to do so. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Your `ForeignKey` in the `profile` class indicates that there may be multiple `profile` instances for a given `User`, so your requirement becomes moot. You would probably want to make it a `OneToOneRelation` instead of a `ForeignKey` first.

Comment: Also please conform to PEP8 when naming your classes (`CamelCase`) to eliminate confusion.

Comment: @Selcuk I am just a beginner. So, can you please explain me what is PEP8 and CamelCase.

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the Python Style Guide and it says that you should name your classes in `CamelCase`, i.e. each word starting with a capital letter and without any separators (for example `RoomUser` instead of `roomuser` and `Profile` instead of `profile`). This is the naming standard most Python developers are used to.

Comment: @Selcuk ok Thankyou, understood. I'll do that from next time. Now, can you tell me a way to do what i have mentioned in my question.

Comment: See my first comment. If you make that change you can simply write `{{ user.user.profile.name }}`.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanku very much for your help. It worked.